# JavaScript replace with RexExp not replacing parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

> the quick brown (error) fox jumps over (error) the lazy dog (error)

I want to output this string without "(error)", so I apply the following code:

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp('(\(error\))', 'g'),'');
```

However, after I run this code the string turns into this:

> the quick brown () fox jumps over () the lazy dog ()

How do I get rid of those parenthesis and why are they not removed even though I escaped them and captured them?

Comment: `"the quick brown (error) fox jumps over (error) the lazy dog (error)".replace(/\(error\)/g,'')`

Comment: The backslashes you escape special chars with must be literal backslashes. In double quoted string literals, the literal backslash is represented with double backslashes. In a regex literal, you can use a single backslash to escape special regex chars.